# Issue with unity animator and any state

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on dragon game. So I make animator for dragon but every things work fine except "any state" in animator. In animator die and attack work attached with "any state". Die state have on one animation and trigger. But attack sub state have more then one animations, bool and id. When attacking bool true and id set, then attack states entering again and again not completing any state.

[image: This is Animator]

[image: This is Attack Sub State]

Comment: have you tried not making it a substatemachine but putting the attack clips into the root machine? You also should reset the bool right when used => better use a Trigger instead of a bool

Comment: I think this would be more suited to be posted at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use trigger like the transition "AnyState => Die", bcz every state is "Any State".If you just use bool/int/float parameter, it will always meet the condition for the transition "AnyState => Attack".

And, Furthermore, "Attack => Attack" is included in "Any State => Attack".

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have your attack state exit onto something else, like enter or idle.

Any State ==> Attack

Idle <== Attack

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In transition settings you can use the "Transition to self" unchecked, so attack will not transit to attack again